# Redirect to specific user page

Tags: php, mysql

I committed a HUGE sin and did some copy and paste programming. I know, I know. BAD programmer! Unfortunately, I am not well versed in PHP and MySQL (although I have enrolled in several Udemy classes to remedy that), and I needed a log in system right away. So, I used the tut found [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL). Now, it works great, but I need the page to redirect to a user specific page on log in, instead of to a single static page as found in the tut.

I added a column to my database at the end called page and populated it with the full URL I want for each user, and tried to change the code to get the value of the page column along with several other solutions from my little knowledge of PHP and things I found online and on SO, but I cannot seem to get the value from the database column "page" for the redirect. It just shows a blank page.

Here is the code that seems to be relevant:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start();

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['p'];

if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
    // Login success        
    header('Location: ../selection.php');
exit();

} else {
    // Login failed 
    header('Location: ../error.php?error=1');
}
} else {
// The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

and (I am not actually sure if this is relevant, but I didn't want anyone to have to go to the tutorial if I could prevent it)

```
<?php
include_once 'psl-config.php';

function sec_session_start() {
$session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
$secure = SECURE;
// This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
$httponly = true;
// Forces sessions to only use cookies.
if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
    exit();
}
// Gets current cookies params.
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
    $cookieParams["path"], 
    $cookieParams["domain"], 
    $secure,
    $httponly);
// Sets the session name to the one set above.
session_name($session_name);
session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}

function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
// Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
    FROM members
   WHERE email = ?
    LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();

    // get variables from result.
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
    $stmt->fetch();

    // hash the password with the unique salt.
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
        // from too many login attempts 

        if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Account is locked 
            // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
            return false;
        } else {
            // Check if the password in the database matches
            // the password the user submitted.
            if ($db_password == $password) {
                // Password is correct!
                // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                            "", 
                                                            $username);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                          $password . $user_browser);
                // Login successful.
                return true;
            } else {
                // Password is not correct
                // We record this attempt in the database
                $now = time();
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // No user exists.
        return false;
    }
}
}

function checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) {
// Get timestamp of current time 
$now = time();

// All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours. 
$valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time 
                         FROM login_attempts 
                         WHERE user_id = ? 
                        AND time > '$valid_attempts'")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);

    // Execute the prepared query. 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    // If there have been more than 5 failed logins 
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 5) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}

function login_check($mysqli) {
// Check if all session variables are set 
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], 
                    $_SESSION['username'], 
                    $_SESSION['login_string'])) {

    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password 
                                  FROM members 
                                  WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        // Bind "$user_id" to parameter. 
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists get variables from result.
            $stmt->bind_result($password);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

            if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                // Logged In!!!! 
                return true;
            } else {
                // Not logged in 
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Not logged in 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Not logged in 
        return false;
    }
} else {
    // Not logged in 
    return false;
}
}

function esc_url($url) {

if ('' == $url) {
    return $url;
}

$url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);

$strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
$url = (string) $url;

$count = 1;
while ($count) {
    $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
}

$url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);

$url = htmlentities($url);

$url = str_replace('&amp;', '&#038;', $url);
$url = str_replace("'", '&#039;', $url);

if ($url[0] !== '/') {
    // We're only interested in relative links from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
    return '';
} else {
    return $url;
}
}
```

I looked at the PHP.net docs, and have tried several solutions I found online, but nothing I have found seems to be working. Do I need to create a function for this? I know I need a better fundamental knowledge of PHP and MySQL for sure.

Let me know if you need more info on this.

Thanks!

Comment: where is the part where you're trying to get the page from the DB...?

Comment: Blank page usually means a problem with your code, details of which are recorded in the server error log. Start there.

Comment: I have tried so many different things, that I just went with the original code. I guess I was trying to avoid heaps of code, although I know I failed at that already.... Should I revise the question to show some attempts?

Comment: There's little point in asking us to help debug your program and then posting something else.

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens Fair enough. I guess I was trying to keep it as least confusing as possible. I see your point though.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `login` function to also get the page-column (`SELECT id, ..., page FROM ...`)

Next, change the `bind_result`: add a parameter after `$salt`: `..., $salt, $page`

Change the `return true` to `return $page;`

Now back in your script that calls the `login` function, change

```
if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
  // Login success        
  header('Location: ../selection.php');
```

to

```
$page = login($email, $password, $mysqli);
if ($page !== false) {
  // Login success        
  header('Location: '. $page);
```

Make sure that your page-column contains valid values at all times though.

Comment: OK, I made the changes and still got a blank page. Maybe the page column contains invalid values? I have http://www.mysite/selection.php and http://www.mysite/admin.php  for values in that column.

Comment: OK, can you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: page in /home/mysite/public_html/includes/process_login.php on line 14

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mysite/public_html/includes/process_login.php:14) in /home/mysite/public_html/includes/process_login.php on line 14

Comment: Oops, yes, obviously, my mistake. Will fix my answer in a few seconds. Sorry. Edit: fixed.

Comment: Cool! That worked, but now the pages do not recognize me as logged in. Could it have to do with this code: <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?> ? This is the code that checks to see if the user is logged in at the beginning of each protected page.

Comment: Do you call `sec_session_start()` in the other pages?

Comment: Yes. There are several pages that each user will have access to. The selection.php page is the hub for several other pages that the user gets access to and contains nothing but links to the other pages.